# Superset ignoring superset_config.py settings

Tags: docker, caching, keycloak, apache-superset, secret-key

I'm running Superset inside a docker container. installed it thru the recommended method explained on the Superset site (clone the GIT project), then tailored the docker-compose-non-dev.yml, .env-non-dev and requirements-local.txt and superset_config.py and pulled the images... it starts and i can log into it. HOWEVER. It keeps saying that it found a default secret key

```
superset_worker_beat | --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
superset_worker_beat | WARNING
superset_worker_beat | --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
superset_worker_beat | A Default SECRET_KEY was detected, please use superset_config.py to override it.
superset_worker_beat | Use a strong complex alphanumeric string and use a tool to help you generate
superset_worker_beat | a sufficiently random sequence, ex: openssl rand -base64 42
superset_worker_beat | --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
superset_worker_beat | --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It keeps saying that it will use default cache setting and they should be redefined properly to avoid data loss:

```
# superset_worker_beat  | Falling back to the built-in cache, that stores data in the metadata database, for the following cache: `FILTER_STATE_CACHE_CONFIG`. It is recommended to use `RedisCache`, `MemcachedCache` or another dedicated caching backend for production deployments
superset_worker_beat | 2023-07-28 12:47:06,744:WARNING:superset.utils.cache_manager:Falling back to the built-in cache, that stores data in the metadata database, for the following cache: FILTER_STATE_CACHE_CONFIG. It is recommended to use RedisCache, MemcachedCache or another dedicated caching backend for production deployments

# superset_worker_beat | Falling back to the built-in cache, that stores data in the metadata database, for the following cache: EXPLORE_FORM_DATA_CACHE_CONFIG. It is recommended to use RedisCache, MemcachedCache or another dedicated caching backend for production deployments

# superset_worker_beat | 2023-07-28 12:47:06,748:WARNING:superset.utils.cache_manager:Falling back to the built-in cache, that stores data in the metadata database, for the following cache: EXPLORE_FORM_DATA_CACHE_CONFIG. It is recommended to use RedisCache, MemcachedCache or another dedicated caching backend for production deployments
```

It authenticates to the default Superset page.

It keeps saying that it found a default secret key:
I've defined both:

```
       SECRET_KEY = "SuperSecretCodeIKnow"
       SUPERSET_SECRET_KEY = "SuperSecretCodeIKnow"
```

It keeps saying that it will use default cache setting and they should be redefined properly to avoid data loss: I've defined all the proper blocks acording to the SS documentation on the superset_config.py file:

```py
       REDIS_HOST = get_env_variable("REDIS_HOST")
       REDIS_PORT = get_env_variable("REDIS_PORT")
       REDIS_CELERY_DB = get_env_variable("REDIS_CELERY_DB", "0")
       REDIS_RESULTS_DB = get_env_variable("REDIS_RESULTS_DB", "1")
       RESULTS_BACKEND = FileSystemCache("/app/superset_home/sqllab")

       CACHE_CONFIG = {
         "CACHE_TYPE": "RedisCache",
         "CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT": 300,
         "CACHE_KEY_PREFIX": "superset_",
         "CACHE_REDIS_HOST": REDIS_HOST,
         "CACHE_REDIS_PORT": REDIS_PORT,
         "CACHE_REDIS_DB": REDIS_RESULTS_DB,
       }

       DATA_CACHE_CONFIG = CACHE_CONFIG

       FILTER_STATE_CACHE_CONFIG = {
         'CACHE_TYPE': 'RedisCache',
         'CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT': 86400,
         "CACHE_REDIS_HOST": REDIS_HOST,
         "CACHE_REDIS_PORT": REDIS_PORT,
         "CACHE_REDIS_DB": 2,
         'CACHE_KEY_PREFIX': 'superset_filter_',

       EXPLORE_FORM_DATA_CACHE_CONFIG = {
         'CACHE_TYPE': 'RedisCache',
         'CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT': 86400,
         'CACHE_KEY_PREFIX': 'superset_explore_form_',
         "CACHE_REDIS_HOST": REDIS_HOST,
         "CACHE_REDIS_PORT": REDIS_PORT,
         "CACHE_REDIS_DB": 3,
         'CACHE_REDIS_URL': 'redis://redis:6379/3'
       }
```

It authenticates to the default Superset page.

Superset is running behind an NginX reverse proxy for the HTTPS capabilities (this works FINE).

I've added the proxy_fix settings to the superset_config.py:

```py
ENABLE_PROXY_FIX = True
PROXY_FIX_CONFIG = {"x_for": 1, "x_proto": 1, "x_host": 1, "x_port": 0, "x_prefix": 1}
```

On this i'm trying to integrate SS with keycloak. i've tried the few recipes here on StackOverFlow, as well as a few other sites. Including the new flask.appbuilder capabilities for keycloak connections for authentications, by all accounts, it should be working, but all i get is always the SS login page.

my requirements-local.txt has the following packages:

```text
itsdangerous==2.0.1 
flask-oidc==1.4.0 
Flask-OpenID==1.3.0 
flask-appbuilder==4.2.0
```

my client_secret.json is like this one (with the correct URLs, Realms, ID,secret):

```json
{
  "web": {
    "issuer": "https://keycloak.local/realms/master",
    "auth_uri": "https://keycloak.local/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
    "client_id": "myclientid",
    "client_secret": "4H6sra49h4BpV4J1SIGlx0YedwqSUNVx",
    "redirect_uris": ["https://superset.local/*"],
    "userinfo_uri": "http://keycloak:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo",
    "token_uri": "http://keycloak:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token",
    "token_introspection_uri": "http://keycloak:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect"
  }
}
```

I've added the following code to superset_config.py:

```py
'''
---------------------------KEYCLOACK ----------------------------
'''
curr  =  os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OID
OIDC_CLIENT_SECRETS =  curr + '/docker/pythonpath_dev/client_secret.json'
OIDC_ID_TOKEN_COOKIE_SECURE = False
OIDC_REQUIRE_VERIFIED_EMAIL = False
OIDC_OPENID_REALM: 'master'
OIDC_INTROSPECTION_AUTH_METHOD: 'client_secret_post'
CUSTOM_SECURITY_MANAGER = OIDCSecurityManager
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = 'Gamma'
OIDC_VALID_ISSUERS = ['https://[url]/realms/[realm]']
'''
--------------------------------------------------------------
'''
```

and created a file named keycloak_security_manager.py and placed it in the /pythonpath_dev path with the following:

```py
from flask import redirect, request
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OID
from superset.security import SupersetSecurityManager
from flask_oidc import OpenIDConnect
from flask_appbuilder.security.views import AuthOIDView
from flask_login import login_user
from urllib.parse import quote
from flask_appbuilder.views import ModelView, SimpleFormView, expose
import logging
import urllib.parse

class OIDCSecurityManager(SupersetSecurityManager):

    def __init__(self, appbuilder):
        super(OIDCSecurityManager, self).__init__(appbuilder)
        if self.auth_type == AUTH_OID:
            self.oid = OpenIDConnect(self.appbuilder.get_app)
        self.authoidview = AuthOIDCView

class AuthOIDCView(AuthOIDView):

    @expose('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def login(self, flag=True):
        sm = self.appbuilder.sm
        oidc = sm.oid

        @self.appbuilder.sm.oid.require_login
        def handle_login():
            user = sm.auth_user_oid(oidc.user_getfield('email'))

            if user is None:
                info = oidc.user_getinfo(['preferred_username', 'given_name', 'family_name', 'email'])
                user = sm.add_user(info.get('preferred_username'), info.get('given_name'), info.get('family_name'),
                                   info.get('email'), sm.find_role('Gamma'))

            login_user(user, remember=False)
            return redirect(self.appbuilder.get_url_for_index)

        return handle_login()

    @expose('/logout/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def logout(self):
        oidc = self.appbuilder.sm.oid

        oidc.logout()
        super(AuthOIDCView, self).logout()
        redirect_url = urllib.parse.quote_plus(request.url_root.strip('/') + self.appbuilder.get_url_for_login)

        return redirect(
            oidc.client_secrets.get('issuer') + '/protocol/openid-connect/logout?client_id='+ oidc.client_secrets.get('client_id')+'&post_logout_redirect_uri=' + quote(redirect_url))
```

On the keycloak side, i've created the realm, created the client, the roles inside the client, a user to whom i've assigned roles with the client but nothing... it ALWAYS pops the Superset auth page. I can login and use it but not thru keycloak.

Comment: Where is your file `superset_config.py` located?  This page on the docs has a little more Docker-specific info: https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/docker/README.md

Comment: it's on the path specified in that document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up starting afresh (benefits of using VMs)... I WAS using the default recommended paths and this last time went for SS 2.1.0. managed to make the SECRET_KEY, and CACHEs work, even got SS passing authentication to KC. (however now i get an error 500 after user validation).
Also, was getting some gunicorn errors which were solved by adding gunincorn to the requirements-local.txt file so it gets upgraded upon start of the docker compose project.

defined the SECRET_KEY in my .env-non-dev file in the /docker dir (created with the 'openssql rand -base64 42' command)

and used the following as cache definitions inside my superset_config.py:

```
FILTER_STATE_CACHE_CONFIG = {
    'CACHE_TYPE': 'RedisCache',
    'CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT': 86400,
    'CACHE_KEY_PREFIX': 'superset_filter_',
    'CACHE_REDIS_URL': 'redis://localhost:6379/2'
}

EXPLORE_FORM_DATA_CACHE_CONFIG = {
    'CACHE_TYPE': 'RedisCache',
    'CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT': 86400,
    'CACHE_KEY_PREFIX': 'superset_data_explorer_',
    'CACHE_REDIS_URL': 'redis://localhost:6379/3'
}

CONTENT_SECURITY_POLICY_WARNING = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I would narrow this down to the main problem: your `superset_config.py` does not appear to be getting picked up at all, based on the warning about a default SECRET_KEY.  Starting in version 2.1.0 Superset should refuse to start up with a default SECRET_KEY, so I assume you're using an earlier version's Docker image.

Per [the docs](https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/docker/README.md) you should put your custom config settings in a file `superset_config.py` that sits in the directory `/docker/pythonpath_dev` under your base directory.  The secret key config could look like:

```
SECRET_KEY = 'ALongComplexStringThatYouDidntGetFromStackOverflow'
```

Once you resolve that, you can tweak the cache, auth, and other settings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ended up starting afresh (benefits of using VMs)... I WAS using the default recommended paths and this last time went for SS 2.1.0. managed to make the SECRET_KEY, and CACHEs work, even got SS passing authentication to KC. (however now i get an error 500 after user validation).